# A matrix $A = (a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ such that $a_{ij} = 0$ for $i>j$ and $a_{ij} = 1$ for $i=1\dots n$. Multiple choice question about the inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a matrix$ A = (a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ with integer entries such that $a_{ij} = 0$ for $i>j$ and $a_{ii} = 1$ for $i=1\dots n$.
Which of the following properties must be true?

1. $A^{-1}$ exists and it has integer entries
2. $A^{-1}$ exists and it has some entries which are nt integers
3. $A^{-1}$ is a polynomial function of $A$ with integer coefficients
4. $A^{-1}$ is not a power of $A$ unless $A$ is an identity matrix

I am confuse about fourth option.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Reading your question, I wonder if instead of the condition "$a_{ij} = 1$ for $i = 1\ldots n$" you in fact want the condition "$a_{ii} = 1$ for $i = 1\ldots n$"? In which case $A$ is triangular and is identically 1 on the diagonal, so the fourth option would actually make sense as a statement.

Comment: ohh yes u r right,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property 1. Certainly. The last property is $A^n = A^{-1}$ iff $A=I$.

Comment: ok,thanks sir,
 what is logic behid this

Comment: @Alka: why did you accept the answer if you don't understand the "logic behid this"?

Comment: option 4 is false?

Comment: @AlkaGoyal no.It is right..